# Additional hypotheses needed for the converse of $\mathscr F \subset H(G)$ normal $\implies$ $\mathscr F ' = \{f' : f \in \mathscr F\}$ normal?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, normal-families

**Problem**

> Show that if $\mathscr F \subset H(G)$ is normal then $\mathscr F' = \{f' : f \in \mathscr F\}$ is also normal. Is the converse true? Can you add something to the hypothesis that $\mathscr F'$ is normal to insure that $\mathscr F$ is normal?

$H(G)$ is the set of holomorphic functions $G \to \mathbb C$, where $G \subset \mathbb C$ is a domain.

**Progress**

I think I was able to prove the forward implication using this previous result:

*Lemma:* $f_n \to f$ in $H(G)$ if and only if $f_n(z) \to f(z)$ uniformly for $z \in \gamma$ for every closed rectifiable $\gamma \subset G$.

The definition of normality is that every sequence in $\mathscr F$ has a convergent subsequence in $H(G)$. By the lemma, the convergence of this subsequence $f_n$ can be viewed as uniform convergence on curves $\gamma$, in which setting it is clear that $f_n' \to f'$. Using the other direction of the lemma then gives that $\mathscr F '$ is normal.

**Question**

For the converse, is the only additional assumption needed an explicit mention that all the elements of $\mathscr F'$ indeed have primitives?

Comment: @jonathan I added the question as it was given to me.

Comment: In this case you already know that every element of $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ has a primitive. You don't, however, know that the family of primitives is locally bounded.

Comment: @jonathan Are you saying that the converse is false unless you further assume that the family of primitives is locally bounded? Or that they are locally bounded, it just needs to be shown?

Comment: I'm saying it needn't be bounded. Indeed, $\mathcal{F}:=\{z\mapsto e^z+w\mid w\in\mathbb{C}\}$ has a singleton for $\mathcal{F}^\prime$, but clearly isn't normal.

Comment: @jonathan Your example makes me think that it's not possible to salvage the converse at all, because any additional hypothesis on $\mathscr F'$ would need to not be satisfied by a singleton set, e.g. finite, closed, bounded, compact, connected, ... Maybe open?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the purest form of the argument, but I'll settle for an equivalence. Clearly, if $\mathcal{F}$ is normal, then for every sequence $(f_n)\subset\mathcal{F}$ there exists $z_0\in G$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ such that $(f_n(z_0))$ is convergent.

On the other hand, if there exists $z_0\in G$ such that $(f_n(z_0))$ is convergent, and $(f_n^\prime)$ is uniformly convergent on compact sets, define $g_n\in H(G)$ by $g_n = f_n - f_n(z_0)$. Since for all $n$ we have $g_n(z_0)=0$, for every $z\in G$ and curve $\gamma$ connecting $z_0$ and $z$ it holds that
$$g_n(z) = \int_\gamma g_n^\prime(w)dw = \int_\gamma f_n^\prime(w)dw.$$
Uniform convergence of $(f_n^\prime)$ on compact sets therefore implies uniform convergence of the $g_n$'s, and finally the convergence of $(f_n(z_0))$ implies that $(f_n)$ is also uniformly convergent on compact sets.

Hence:

> Provided that $\mathcal{F}^\prime$ is normal, then $\mathcal{F}$ is normal if and only if for every sequence $(f_n)\subset\mathcal{F}$ there exists $z_0\in G$ and a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$  such that $(f_{n_k}(z_0))$ converges.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your second paragraph. How is the uniform convergence of $(f_n')$ on compacta used? Why do those two assumptions imply that $(g_n)$ converges uniformly on compacta? Also, I think the notation should be $g_n \in H(G)$ rather than $g_n(z)$. And is "compacta" a standard synonym for "compact sets"?

Comment: @DanielH., is it clearer now? Regarding 'compacta', it's something one of my professors used to say, and it never occurred to me that it might not be commonplace until I just now failed to find a similar instance on Google.

Comment: @DanielH. "Compacta" is the plural of "compactum", it is standard usage, though perhaps it may be less standard in English than in German.